# VBA EXCEL - Public Array losing its value at each new code execution

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am currently developing a code in VBA Excel.

This code generates a 3 dimensional array based on userinputs in the worksheets.

The idea is to re-run this code every time userinput is changed.

But due to heavy calculation time, I want to keep previously calculated data in the array and only amend the array for the rows / columns that have received new user input.

My original idea was therefore to:

1. declare the array as public and
2. use "redim preserve" for each new code execution (i.e. each new update)

However, I realise that at every new code execution, the array comes in empty and the full calculation is re-run...

Could someone help to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance
Al

Comment: I see a lot of story about a code, but I don't see any code....

Comment: @user2598725 .. use static var ..

Comment: I'm looking for a code also.

Comment: @matzone: That would probably either be a `Global` or a `Public` module level variable in VBA.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. In order to help you it's really best if you can show the code you're using as well as the description of the problem, otherwise we're really guessing on how to help you. Check out the [About] and [ask] pages to see how to get the most from the site.

Comment: I think you may be **re-declaring** your *array* in a [nested loop](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=what%20is%20a%20nested%20loop). The declaration of a public variable goes outside any module *(before any `Sub` and/or between `Option Explicit` and first `Sub`/`Function`)*

Comment: Hi and thanks for rapid feedback. I am not giving the code as it is a huge set of lines really...

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function UseTestVar()
    Static TestVar(10) As Integer

    Debug.Print TestVar(1)

    TestVar(1) = TestVar(1) + 1
End Function

Sub Test3()
    UseTestVar
End Sub
```

Every execution time the `TestVar(1)` value is incremented.

Edit;

So yes, you need to have a function to "hold" you the "global" variable, and use that function to do all the stuff with it... or return it, or... Without knowing your code I must leave it to you to figure out the working implementation.

Comment: If you think it was helpful you can accept the answer. Also your question was quite broad, so keep asking more questions as you might encounter some technicalities during implementation.